# Why is Visual Studio not removing files/folders when switching branches?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am using VS 2019 Community along with the integrated Git functionality to manage my code, and I have noticed recently that when switching from, for example, branch `A` to branch `B` where branch `A` contains a directory `D` with a solution that branch `B` does not have, Visual Studio fails to remove directory `D` and all the untracked files within its directory structure. When I close Visual Studio and perform the same operation switching from branch `A` to branch `B` using the command line, directory `D` and all its subfolders and files are removed as expected. However, if Visual Studio is open while I switch branches on the command line, it exhibits the same undesired behavior where it does not remove directory `D` indicating to me that perhaps Visual Studio is blocking Git somehow from doing what it would normally do when switching branches. The untracked files in question reside in the `bin` and `obj` subdirectories under the project contained in directory `D` and appear to be Visual Studio build artifacts, such as `.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.AssemblyAttributes` and `<solution_name>.AssemblyInfo.cs`.

My question is - why does Visual Studio have this behavior and what can I do to prevent it from happening? Ultimately, since the files are untracked, it has no effect on branch `B`, but it is still sufficiently annoying that these VS artifacts are lingering in a place they don't belong, and I would like to correct it if possible.

Comment: I do not understand what do you meant by this line: `"Visual Studio fails to remove directory D and all the untracked files within its directory structure"`. Have you tried to switch git branches through command line while VS was open?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried switching git branches through the command line while VS was open and I experience the same behavior where directory D is not being removed. I will update my original question with that information.

Comment: It sounds like you're not ignoring the `bin`, `obj` and/or `.vs` folders from your git repository, which is a bad idea for a myriad of reasons, not the least of which the fact that VS actively uses files in those folders.